# Get multiple transaction receipts at once

Tags: ethers.js

I have following flow: Need to take for every block transactions, and for every transaction the receipt to extract the logs. Currently i'm using `transaction.wait()` to get the transaction receipt, i saw there is a method `provider.getTransactionReceipt(txHash)` but both of these approaches are very consuming in perspective for requests to infura. Is there anyway to get all the receipts for transactions in single block or something like this to save some requests?

Answer (score 1):

> very consuming in perspective for requests to infura.

Nobody is forcing you to use slow and expensive Infura.

[Run your own node](https://twitter.com/moo9000/status/1370323189486784513) and any JSON-RPC call on localhost is basically free.